# Div resize horizontally like in twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add functionality like in twitter when scroll down div elongates horizontally when click more button. How can i do so?

Comment: No i meant to say horizontally when click more, new messages are added to div how to change it's height when append new data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to the tweet stream on twitter.com then it's a bit more complex than elongating a `<div>`.  Behind the scenes what's happening is javascript running on the page make an AJAX call for more tweets.  That data is then rendered to HTML and appended to the container `<div>`.  In addition the "elongation" effect is likely an animation that simply alters the height of the newly appended content.

A great place to start is with jQuery and the [Getting Started with jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery).

Also worth checking out are the doc pages for:

- [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [$.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)
- [$.slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)

Comment: Yeah it is something like that but how to alter the height of div gradually and each time i append new data.